# Prove $\lim_{z \rightarrow i} z^2 = -1$ using the definition of limits.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $\lim_{z \rightarrow i} z^2 = -1$ using the definition of limits.

The proof is given as follows:
$|z^2 -(-1)| = |z-i||z-i +2i| \le |z-i| (|z-i| + 2)$.  Now if $|z-i| \lt \delta$ the right hand side of the equation is less than $\delta(\delta + 2)$, so to ensure that it is less than $\epsilon$, we choose $\delta$ to be smaller than each either of the numbers $\epsilon / 3$ and $1$ and get:

$|z-i|(|z-i| + 2) \lt \frac{\epsilon}{3}(1 + 2) = \epsilon$.

My questions are:  Why does choosing delta to be this ensure this result?  and, where did $ \frac{\epsilon}{3}(1 + 2)$ come from?

Comment: You probably want $\delta$ smaller than *both of* $\epsilon/3$ and $1$. "Either of" is ambigous, and many people will interepret it to mean "one of."

Answer (score 1):

If $\delta=\min( \frac{\epsilon}{3},1)$, that is $\delta \leq 1$ and $\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

We have
$$|z-i| <\delta \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

and

$$(|z-i|+2)<\delta+2\leq 1+2=3$$

Multiply them up and you will get the desired result.